# Не рисуется квадрат в path на java в canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, path

При попытки нарисовать с помощью путей (path) на Canvas квадрат, или несколько квадратов, они не рисуются. Однако если нарисовать круг с помощью путей, то он рисуется свободно. Как мне нарисовать квадрат именно с помощью путей?

```
Path path = new Path();
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    path.addRect(100, 200, 100, 50, Path.Direction.CW);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: Прочтите внимательнее в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path#addRect(float,%2520float,%2520float,%2520float,%2520android.graphics.Path.Direction)) что означают аргументы метода `addRect` - у Вас левая и правая стороны совпадают, а верхняя ниже чем нижняя.

Comment: @woesss А разница? Всё равно квадрат рисуется, если рядом с ним нарисовать с помощью path круг. А без круга он не рисуется

Comment: Ну Вам нет разницы - мне так и тем более... Покажете свой код, который рисует квадрат с кругом - тогда можно будет говорить о разнице. Представленный кусок кода должен нарисовать вертикальную полоску шириной 5px и высотой 150px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл, почему у меня не отображался квадрат. Просто напросто у меня был не тот API. А на телефоне всё отображалось